# How to deserialize JsonString using ObjectMapper with Generic Type of a class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, objectmapper

Let's say If I have a model class `ResponseModel`

```
@Setter // This one not working
public class ResponseModel<T> {

    private Class<T> responseClass;
    private String content; // JsonString

    public <T> T getContent() throws IOException { 
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return mapper.readValue(content, responseClass);
    }
}
```

What I want to do is I want to pass Generic Type to the class `ResponseModel` and when I call method `getContent()` it should return the mapped object according to responseClass

Here is an example that I want to do it

```
 // Color Pojo
    @Data
    public class Color {

        private String nameValue;
        private String hexValue;

    }

 // prepare mocked content
    final String content = "{\n" +
            "\"nameValue\":\"red\",\n" +
            "\"hexValue\":\"FFFFFF\"\n" +
            "}";

 // Declare ResponseModel Object
    ResponseModel<Color> response = new ResponseModel<>();
    response.setContent(content);
    response.getContent().getNameValue(); // should return red
    response.getContent().getHexValue(); // should return FFFFFF
```

anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a static method to deserialize an object with generic type

```
public class MyDeserializer {

    private static final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public static  <T> T convertValue(String content, Class<T> contentClass) throws IOException {
        Assert.notNull(content, "Content cannot be null");
        Assert.notNull(contentClass, "Content class must be specified");
        return objectMapper.readValue(content, contentClass);
    }
}
```

and to test your method :

```
Color color = MyDeserializer.convertValue("{" +
            "\"nameValue\":\"red\"," +
            "\"hexValue\":\"FFFFFF\"" + "}", Color.class);
assertEquals("red", color.getNameValue());
assertEquals("FFFFFF", color.getHexValue());
```

In this way, you can use the deserializer for any class at runtime.

**UPDATE**

To make your example work you need to remove  before getContent to match with generic type T from class.

```
public  T getContent() throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return  mapper.readValue(content, responseClass);
}
```

and to use your method :

```
responseModel.setContent("{" +
         "\"nameValue\":\"red\"," +
         "\"hexValue\":\"FFFFFF\"" + "}");
responseModel.setResponseClass(Color.class);
```

At runtime the generic type is replaced with Object, so you must specify the expected class.

I still consider that the first solution is the clean one. You are asking if it is possible to deduce T class, but it is not possible to see the type of T at runtime.

Comment: I know this one will work but I want to know if it is possible to use Generic Type to deserilize within a class which I think that would be more convenience.

Comment: I added an update, your solution will work if you set the responseClass from outside.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately, it is not possible to do what I want. by the way, thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can write an interface with `JsonSubTypes` to be automatically deserialized as follows:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"type"})
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Subclass1.class, name = "SUBCLASS1"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Subclass2.class, name = "SUBCLASS2")
})
public interface DeserializableModelInterface {

}
```

and write your `ResponseModel` with this specific object

```
public class ResponseModel<T extends AbstractDeserializer> {

    private T body;

    public ResponseModel(T body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

    public T getBody() {
        return body;
    }
}
```

Your `body` is a specific object that you can get at runtime without converting json explicitly

In your `Subclass1`, `Subclass2` and so on, you will have an additional json property that will permit to jackson to de/serialize automatically

```
    {
        "type": "SUBCLASS1"
        ... other properties
    }
```

To Avoid manual mapping for subclass value, you can use class name for example:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "class")
```

Comment: That means when we want to use a class as a response class, we need to put the class in DeserializableModelInterface  everytime?

Comment: i specified a value for each mapping because i want to define how it can be deserialized. But it's not required. Updated answer with further details

Comment: I see but I think for my case I cannot have the additional json property in the response class. Is there another way?

Comment: Update your question with your requirements, so people will avoid to lose time in solution you don’t need

Comment: Recommend name?